# Mapping two references in the same class but reference class has Composite key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following database tables (These are abbreviated for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prod_uom](
    [prod_id] [dbo].[uid] NOT NULL,       --Primary key
    [uom_type] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL,  --Primary Key
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[order_line](
    [order_line_id] [dbo].[uid] NOT NULL,  --Primary key
    [prod_id] [dbo].[uid] NOT NULL,        --Foreign key
    [uom_type_requested] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL, --Foreign key
    [uom_specified] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL        --Foreign key
)
```

Entity I'm having trouble with looks like this (Abbreviated):

```
public class OrderLine
{
     public virtual Guid OrderLineId { get; private set; }
     public virtual ProductUom UomRequested { get; set; }
     public virtual ProductUom UomSpecified { get; set; }
}

public class ProductUom
{
    public virtual Guid ProductId { get; private set; }
    public virtual decimal UomType { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I have 2 References to the **PROD_UOM** table inside my **ORDER_LINE** class.  My first attempt at mapping this was the following:

```
public OrderLineMap()
{
    Table("ORDER_LINE");
    Id(x => x.OrderLineId, "ORDER_LINE_ID");

    References(x => x.UomSpecified)
        .Columns(new string[] { "PROD_ID", "UOM_SPECIFIED" });

    References(x => x.UomRequested)
        .Columns(new string[] { "PROD_ID", "UOM_TYPE_REQUESTED" });
}
```

This mapping gets the dreaded error (PROD_ID is referenced twice):

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 17 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=17.
```

### Is there an easy way to map this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't map the same column twice so my suggestion would be to split the PROD_ID column in ORDER_LINE into two, PROD_ID_SPEC and PROD_ID_REQ.

There are some other options but that is the one I would suggest as they are probably even more inelegant than that.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could do it this way but was hoping there was another solution.  I don't think the DBA will go for this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why wouldn't he? He already has a column UOM_TYPE_REQUESTED and a column UOM_SPECIFIED even though technically you could just use a single column UOM_TYPE since there are no real structural differences between "ProductUom's", it is just contextual.  This will have to happen or you'll have to really mess up the domain objects or generate the SQL yourself.

Comment: The prod_id will never change in our case.  It would just be additional data that we would be storing in that table.  We'll see how it plays out though.

Comment: You gotta think about it with the perspective of NHibernate though.  If the product id were to change (ie you have changed the object on one of the ProductUom references) the other would be affected.  I'm unsure as to whether NHibernate intended this problem to arise (they don't want you to map the same column twice) or just a side effect.  All I know is you need column(s) for each of the keys for each of your references (2 refs * 2 key columns = 4 columns).  Sounds like another case of the DBA ruining everything :-D

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help here.  Turns out this was a big misunderstanding by me due to no documentation on the uom_specified column.  It was actually a flag that was related to the **SINGLE** ProdUom related to that table.  You know what they say about assuming ...

Comment: That's funny cause another suggestion I was gonna give would be to create a boolean flag to denote whether something was specified instead of two references, but I didn't want to cause a lot of work (schema and domain objects).  Glad it worked out for you though!